# How to place two set of blocks side by side (in JavaScript object style)?

Tags: javascript, vim

In other words, how to turn this:

```
hello:
goodbye:

'Hello'
'Goodbye'
```

Into this in Vim?

```
hello: 'Hello',
goodbye: 'Goobye'
```

I want to do this because I have a long list of strings that I'm grabbing from an Exel sheet which I need to turn into JavaScript objects

Comment: Not that it's not possible using Vim but imo it's much easier to paste those long lists in excel in seperate columns and copy/paste the end result in Vim to add some final formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in comments, you might be overcomplicating things by doing this in Vim. Using Excel, it's easy to place two columns next to each other and copy/paste those results to Vim for final adjusting *(if needed)*

Following substitution command might get you started for a Vim only solution

> 0,/\v^$/-1s/\v(.*)/\=submatch(0).getline(line('.')+3).','

**The gist of this is to**

- Set a range from the top of the file to the first empty line minus 1
- Capture the entire line in a group
- Replace the entire line with the captured group and append the content of the current line + 3

I don't have a solution to make the +3 variable so

- You need to work out the #lines between your first and second "column" to pass in the substitution command
- You still need to manually delete all the lines from you second column afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with macros this will help. If not just follow the keystrokes to record 1 block side-by-side and then reuse the macro.

1. Go to the top of the file (in this case, have your cursor on **hello:**) and type the following to record a macro.

> ```
> qq}jdd''pkJA,<escape key>j
> ```

2. This should do the process correctly for the first instance. To repeat press `@q` if you need to repeat the process 100 times press `100@q`
3. When you need to run the macro, have the cursor on the next line you need to pair side-by-side and run `@q`